# How to change navbar after login using session and before login show that page

Tags: php, session-cookies

I tried and want (index.php) my home page its show the webpage but the navbar extreme right show  Login menu. After login session will created and navbar changed from login to logout. then its session access remaining page also.

**Login.php**

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>

<?php
 session_start(); 
 require_once 'dbconnect.php';

 if (isset($_SESSION['userSession'])!="") {
       header("Location: index.php");
      exit;
  }

 if (isset($_POST['btn-login'])) {

 $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
 $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

 $email = $DBcon->real_escape_string($email);
 $password = $DBcon->real_escape_string($password);

 $query = $DBcon->query("SELECT user_id, email, password FROM tbl_users                   WHERE email='$email' and password='$password'");
    $row=$query->fetch_array();

 $count = $query->num_rows; // if email/password are correct returns must be 1 row

if ($count==1) {
    $_SESSION['userSession'] = $row['user_id'];
header("Location: index.php");
} else {
    $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> &nbsp; Invalid Username or Password !
            </div>";
}
$DBcon->close();
}
?>
```

**Index.php**

```
<?php 
 session_start();
 include_once 'dbconnect.php';

 if (!isset($_SESSION['userSession'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
  }

 $query = $DBcon->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['userSession']);
 $userRow=$query->fetch_array();
 $DBcon->close();

 ?>
```

**navbar**

```
<?php   
if(isset($_SESSION['userSession'])) {
    echo '<li class="dropdown"><a href="logout.php"><span>Log Out</span></a>   </li>';
} else {
    echo '<li class="dropdown"><a href="login.php"><span>Log In</span></a></li>';
} 
?>
```

This is for my coding.  Can't open the file index.php before login. Now I need your help, index.php file open without login but the navbar show login menu. Once login it replace logout menu.

Thanks for you 
advance reply to me

Answer (score 0):

Hope you will find it useful. You can make the structure like below and try further. Please findout the commented lines to get more understanding of code.

Your index file : index.php

```
<?php
require('configuration.php'); #Database connection and other site configuration

if(!isset($_SESSION['userSession'])){
header("location:login.php"); #Redirection
die();
}
?>

<script language="javascript">
location.href='home.php';
</script>
```

Header file : header.php

```
<?php  
if(isset($_SESSION['userSession'])) {
echo '<li class="dropdown"><a href="logout.php"><span>Log Out</span></a></li>';
} else {
echo '<li class="dropdown"><a href="login.php"><span>Log In</span></a></li>';
} 

?>
```

Home page : home.php

```
<?php
require('configuration.php'); #Database connection and other site configuration

if(!isset($_SESSION['userSession'])){ #Do login first if user is guest user
header("location:login.php"); #Redirection
die();
}

#Active session will perform ...
$id = $_SESSION['userSession'];
$query = $DBcon->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE user_id=".$id);
while($userRow = $query->fetch_array();){
extract($userRow);
}

require_once("header.php"); #header file contains navigation bar
?>
```

Login page : login.php

```
<?php

require('configuration.php'); #Database and other site configuration

if(isset($_POST['btn-login'])){ #Login form submission and generate a $_SESSION['userSession']
....
}

require_once("header.php"); #header file contains navigation bar
?>

<!--Your login page form </ CODE> will be here -->
```